# List of Algorithms not spaced like List of Figures/Tables

Tags: lyx, tocloft

I am using LyX, but I will provide the MWE TeX code below (there is probably a lot of irrelevant code snippets, but I don't want to remove anything that is possibly relevant to the question).

Basically, I've eventually finalized the output I want, except for the LoA is being printed what looks like one line lower than the LoF.

I have control over the preamble, which has the following code currently.

```
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\patchcmd{\listof}% <cmd>
  {\float@listhead}% <search>
  {\@namedef{l@#1}{\l@figure}\float@listhead}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>

\preto\figure{%
  \ifnum\value{figure}=0\addtocontents{lof}{{\bfseries Chapter \thechapter\vskip10pt}}\fi
}
\preto\table{%
  \ifnum\value{table}=0\addtocontents{lot}{{\bfseries Chapter \thechapter\vskip10pt}}\fi
}
\preto\algorithm{%
  \ifnum\value{algorithm}=0\addtocontents{loa}{{\bfseries Chapter \thechapter\vskip10pt}}\fi
}

\cftsetindents{figure}{0em}{3.5em}
\cftsetindents{table}{0em}{3.5em}
```

---

The preto is used to add a chapter headings inside the LoX.

The cftsetindents is adding some spacing to make the LoX output more legible.

Below, I paste the complete MWE, after an image showcasing my issue visually.

Any help in correcting the spacing around the LoA is greatly appreciated.

Side note: I do manage to correct *this* issue by using `\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}`, but then the chapter headings become misaligned and it is a worse issue to solve.

[image: LoA in forefront, with LoF remnants above it.]

```
%% LyX 2.2.1 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[12pt,english]{extreport}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{berasans}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{cmtl}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{luainputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2.5cm,bmargin=2.5cm,lmargin=3cm,rmargin=2cm}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
%% Because html converters don't know tabularnewline
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}
\floatstyle{ruled}
\newfloat{algorithm}{tbp}{loa}[chapter]
\providecommand{\algorithmname}{Algorithm}
\floatname{algorithm}{\protect\algorithmname}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tocloft}


%\let\l@table\l@figure

\patchcmd{\listof}% <cmd>
  {\float@listhead}% <search>
  {\@namedef{l@#1}{\l@figure}\float@listhead}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>

\preto\figure{%
  \ifnum\value{figure}=0\addtocontents{lof}{{\bfseries Chapter \thechapter\vskip10pt}}\fi
}
\preto\table{%
  \ifnum\value{table}=0\addtocontents{lot}{{\bfseries Chapter \thechapter\vskip10pt}}\fi
}
\preto\algorithm{%
  \ifnum\value{algorithm}=0\addtocontents{loa}{{\bfseries Chapter \thechapter\vskip10pt}}\fi
}

\cftsetindents{figure}{0em}{3.5em}
\cftsetindents{table}{0em}{3.5em}

\@ifundefined{showcaptionsetup}{}{%
 \PassOptionsToPackage{caption=false}{subfig}}
\usepackage{subfig}
\AtBeginDocument{
  \def\labelitemii{\(\circ\)}
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents{}

\pagebreak{}

\listoffigures{}

\pagebreak{}

\listof{algorithm}{List of Algorithms}

\pagebreak{}

\chapter{Background}

\begin{figure}[H]
\caption{Fig1}
\end{figure}


\chapter{System Design}

\begin{figure}[H]
\caption{Fig2}
\end{figure}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\begin{algorithmic}[1] \If{$x < \mu$} \State{$\hat{x} \leftarrow 0$} \Else{ } \State{$\hat{x} \leftarrow x$} \EndIf \end{algorithmic}\caption{Custom Zero Minus Means Algorithm}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
```

and `\noindent` before "Chapter"

```
\preto\figure{%
  \ifnum\value{figure}=0\addtocontents{lof}{{\noindent\bfseries Chapter \thechapter\vskip10pt}}\fi
}
\preto\table{%
  \ifnum\value{table}=0\addtocontents{lot}{{\noindent\bfseries Chapter \thechapter\vskip10pt}}\fi
}
\preto\algorithm{%
  \ifnum\value{algorithm}=0\addtocontents{loa}{{\noindent\bfseries Chapter \thechapter\vskip10pt}}\fi
}
```

[image]

---

Here is another suggestion using package `tocbasic` instead `tocloft`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,english]{extreport}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{berasans}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{cmtl}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{luainputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2.5cm,bmargin=2.5cm,lmargin=3cm,rmargin=2cm}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
% Because html converters don't know tabularnewline
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}
\floatstyle{ruled}
\newfloat{algorithm}{tbp}{loa}[chapter]
\providecommand{\algorithmname}{Algorithm}
\floatname{algorithm}{\protect\algorithmname}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tocbasic}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  indent=0pt,
  numwidth=3.5em,
  onstarthigherlevel=\vskip10pt\LastTOCLevelWasLower
]{tocline}{figure}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  level=0,
  beforeskip=10pt,
  indent=0pt,
  numwidth=0pt,
  entryformat=\textbf,
  linefill=\hfill,
  pagenumberformat=\@gobble
]{tocline}{chapterinlistof}

\patchcmd{\listof}% <cmd>
  {\float@listhead}% <search>
  {\@namedef{l@#1}{\l@figure}\float@listhead}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>

\preto\figure{%
  \ifnum\value{figure}=0\addcontentsline{lof}{chapterinlistof}{Chapter \thechapter}\fi
}
\preto\table{%
  \ifnum\value{table}=0\addcontentsline{lot}{chapterinlistof}{Chapter \thechapter}\fi
}
\preto\algorithm{%
  \ifnum\value{algorithm}=0\addcontentsline{loa}{chapterinlistof}{Chapter \thechapter}\fi
}

\@ifundefined{showcaptionsetup}{}{%
 \PassOptionsToPackage{caption=false}{subfig}}
\usepackage{subfig}
\AtBeginDocument{
  \def\labelitemii{\(\circ\)}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listof{algorithm}{List of Algorithms}
\chapter{Background}
\begin{figure}[H]
\caption{Fig1}
\end{figure}
\chapter{System Design}
\begin{figure}[H]
\caption{Fig2}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[H]
\caption{Fig3}
\end{figure}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\begin{algorithmic}[1] \If{$x < \mu$} \State{$\hat{x} \leftarrow 0$} \Else{ } \State{$\hat{x} \leftarrow x$} \EndIf \end{algorithmic}\caption{Custom Zero Minus Means Algorithm}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Fantastic, I've just tried the first approach, and it works. Do you know why the indenting was happening for all but the first chapter heading as my code was when using [titles]?

Comment: Also, are either of your fixes preferred, or will both work equally well? Thanks again.

Comment: `tocloft` without option `titles` sets the parindent to `0pt` inside the TOC and the lists. The first chapter entry starts the first paragraph below the list heading, therefore the first one is not intended. I think both suggestions will work. But I am more familar with `tocbasic`, so I would use the second.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I appreciate your time!

Comment: how to add the name of chapter its number?